# jQuery conflict with prototype.js: Calender icon is not popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded some logic using jQuery. For that to work I need to place:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

But if i place that, then my calender icon is not popping.
But if I remove, logic won't work. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You already might be using another jQuery on same page, that is conflicting with this one. Do you observe any errors in console?

Comment: I am getting the following error  Cannot set property '0' of undefined in a file called prototype.js

Comment: Where is the following error?

Comment: setStyle: function(element, style) {
    element = $(element);
    for (name in style)
      element.style[name.camelize()] = style[name];
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined (repeated 2 times)
  },
here in this I am getting error.

Comment: @ParkashKumar,above is the following error.

Comment: Can you share the code of your page?

Comment: Should I share prototype.js code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97926/discussion-between-shruthi-sathyanarayana-and-parkash-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve conflict between `jQuery` and `prototype.js`, you need to put jQuery in `No-Conflict` mode by assigning it to new qualified variable as following:

```
/* Add prototype.js before jQuery */
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

/* Assign jQuery to qualified var */
var jQuery_1.11.3 = jQuery.noConflict();

/* Use in your code */
jQuery_1.11.3(document).ready(function() {
    // Your jQuery dependent code.
});
```

OR, you can include `jQuery` before `prototype.js` and use full jQuery keyword for your logic, as following:

```
/* Include jQuery before prototype.js */
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>  

/* Use full jQuery var name to reference jQuery */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Your jQuery dependent code.
});
```

[**Reference**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that jQuery is first...

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
```

Then use `jQuery` or `window.jQuery` in your code that uses jQuery instead of `$` which is what prototype is using.

You can also wrap in an iife if you need to...

```
(function(w,$){
    //in here $ is jQuery, w.$ is prototype
}(window, jQuery))
```